# Can't redirect standard output

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, redirect

I'm following along with the examples in Chapter 6 *Redirection* of *The Linux Command Line* (2012).  I am trying to redirect the standard output of an `ls` command to a text file.  I keep receiving a permission denied error. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.  See below:

```
ta2tyrants@Vaio:/$ ls -l /usr/bin >> ls-output.txt
bash: ls-output.txt: Permission denied
```

I tried to run this command using root access and get the same error:

```
ta2tyrants@Vaio:/$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin >> ls-output.txt
bash: ls-output.txt: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:** redirect to a file you can write to

Your current working directory is `/`, which by default can only be modified by root. Type `cd ~` to change to your home folder, or `cd` followed by the path to a directory you *can* write to, then do it again.

**Solution 2:** redirect with `sh` under `sudo`

Shell redirections are not passed along to programs. This means that even if execute a program under `sudo`, redirection (like `>>`) will still be performed under your account. This is what happens:

```
  sudo         ls -l /usr/bin         >>/ls-output.txt
-------------------------------------------------------
|     execute external program      | redirect stdout |       what your shell sees
| sudo | command to execute as root |                            what sudo sees
```

If you want to `sudo` a redirect, you need to run a shell as root. You can do this:

```
     sudo         sh   -c '      ls -l /usr/bin           >>/ls-output.txt   '
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      execute external program (pass the single-quoted string verbatim)      | your shell
|    sudo       |                command to execute as root                   |    sudo
                | sh | -c | execute external program |    redirect stdout     | root shell
```

That way, the redirect is part of a `sh` invocation that is done under `sudo`.

**Solution 3:** redirect with `tee` under `sudo`

As [Oli♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358714/cant-redirect-standard-output#comment459219_358721), you can also pipe your command into tee:

```
       ls -l /usr/bin          |     sudo        tee /ls-output.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| execute external program | pipe |      execute external program       | your shell
                                  |  sudo  | command to execute as root |    sudo
```

Note that the `tee` is executed under `sudo`, but not the `ls`. This is because `tee` needs root priveleges (to write to `/ls-output.txt`), and `ls` does not. If the program generating output *did* need root privileges, you would need to `sudo` both of them.

```
   sudo        ls -l /root              |    sudo        tee /ls-output.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     execute external program      | pipe |     execute external program      | your shell
| sudo | command to execute as root |                                             sudo #1
                                           | sudo | command to execute as root |  sudo #2
```

Also, if you don't want the output displayed on the screen, you can add `>/dev/null` to the very end of the line.

Comment: You can also pipe into tee to redirect as root.